# How to draw transparent rubberband on OpenGL scene

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, rubber-band

i'm using OpenGL for showing grabbed frames from video camera with texture mapping. There is no problem at all but i have to select some region of the grabbed frame then i have to zoom it, first of all i can't draw a Rubber rectangle it must be transparent when i select the some region of grabbed frame i have to see textured frame transparently could you gimme some piece of code or clue, btw i'm showing grabbed frames like that any suggestion will be good for me...

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGenTextures(1, &m_pTextureId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_pTextureId);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
}
void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0,0,w,h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-1,1,-1,1,-1,1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
void GLWidget::setTextureData(BYTE *data, int width, int height)
{
    makeCurrent();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    if (m_isTextured)
        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,width,height,GL_BGRA_EXT,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,data);
    else
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,3,width,height,0,GL_BGRA_EXT,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,m_pTextureId);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0);glVertex2f(-1.0,-1.0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0,1.0);glVertex2f(-1.0,1.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0,1.0);glVertex2f(1.0,1.0);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0,0.0);glVertex2f(1.0,-1.0);
    glEnd();
    swapBuffers();
}
```

I'm passing captured frame data to setTextureData it's working but i dunno does it good way ...

---

Thanks for reply @genpfault,

i used x1=0, y1=0, x2=1, y2=1 but it's  drawing rectangle to all texture area. and draws 1 more rectangle to coordinates x1,y1... . How can i fix it. Btw how can i remove that rectangle ?, There is one more issue if i draw a rectangle then texture again rectangle going invisible ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just draw a translucent (alpha < 1.0) [rectangle](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glRect.xml):

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND); 
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glColor4ub(255, 255, 255, 128);
glRectf(x1, y1, x2, y2);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```